# Ticks not showing correctly on colorbar

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

With the following code:

```
import matplotlib.cm as cm
from matplotlib import colors
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

colormap = cm.YlOrRd

norm = colors.LogNorm(vmin=100, vmax=10000)
sm = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=colormap, norm=norm)
sm.set_array([])
cb = plt.colorbar(sm, ticks = [1,10,100,1000,10000,100000]) 
plt.show()
```

I would expect the ticks to be "100 1000 10000" but instead I see powers of 10 instead. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well there is a way

```
cb = plt.colorbar(sm, ticks = [1,10,100,1000,10000,100000], format='%.0f')
```

this takes off the 10^m notation, you just need to precise the format

```
format='%.0f'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `vmin` is 100 but you are setting a tick at 1 and 10. The `vmax` is 10000 but the highest tick is at 100000. I have corrected the tick values to match with your desired color bar.

While using `format` is the best solution, an alternative way could be the following

```
tick_list = [100,1000,10000]
cb = plt.colorbar(sm, ticks = tick_list)
cb.set_ticklabels(list(map(str, tick_list)))
```

[image]